# how to call parent of shouldComponentUpdate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parent-child

I want to overwrite `shouldComponentUpdate` in react.
I tried to write code like this :

```
  shouldComponentUpdate() {
    console.log("should component update called");
    return Object.getPrototypeOf(this).shouldComponentUpdate();
  }
```

and

```
shouldComponentUpdate() {
    console.log("should component update called");
    return parent.shouldComponentUpdate();
  }
```

I also tried to bind this in the constructor. I was wondering how can I do this in react

Comment: What is the goal? What are you trying to prevent / achieve?

Comment: I'm just curious, I want to how can I call parent function in react

Comment: Pass the function as prop to the child.